# Automatically evaluate next cell

Tags: evaluation

I am new to *Mathematica*. I am trying to achieve the following:

I need one input cell in which I set parameters, then another input cell where functions are defined and calculations are performed. Finally one output cell for the result. I want to hide the second input cell which contains a lot of code. When I change the parameters in the first input cell and evaluate it, it should automatically evaluate the second hidden input cell and update the result. I wasn't able to achieve this as I have to evaluate the second input cell separately. Also, it would be a requirement that there be no additional code in the first input cell.

Comment: Hide your cell but add a `CellTag`, then with `Cells[CellTags->...]` and `NotebookEvaluate` you will get what you need.

Comment: Sorry, not entirly sure how to do this. So, I added a CellTag called "test" to the second input cell. Now where do I put Cells[CellTags->test] and NotebookEvaluate?

Comment: you can hide the second cell, change the first cell as you want and then select all (CTL+A) and then run. all cells will be evaluated.

Comment: I think that this problem, as you described it, will either have 1. easy but imperfect solutions, or 2. solutions that follow your specification precisely, but require advanced knowledge of Mathematica to implement (along the lines of what Kuba said).   If you describe *why* you need this, we might be able to give an easy solution that's still useful.  How familiar are you with Mathematica, especially notebook programming?  If you aren't, I'd recommend going with (1.).

Comment: Algohi, this doesnt work, it opens all the hidden cells.

Comment: Szablocs, I am not familiar with notebook programming. Why do I need it? Well, there is no real reason, wouldn't this be a natural thing to want to have inputs separated from calculations?

Comment: @Frank, my point is precisely that making these short suggestions work involves extra work and a lot of learning about how the FE/notebooks work.  It's probably not worth the effort for you.  Instead, describe the problem you have (not the solution you propose to it), then people can suggest alternative solutions.  For example, why don't you just define a function in a large cell, mark it as initialization, hide it, then have small cells calling that function?  I have the feeling that since you're new to Mathematica, you're trying to do things in an unnatural and difficult way.

Comment: What I describe above is a rather typical workflow.  There's a (folded, i.e. not visible by default) initialization section at the beginning of the notebook.  When you evaluate anything in the notebook for the first time, it'll ask you whether you want to run the initialization code first.  Just click yes, and it'll do it.  You don't need to *look* at that large code block to run it.  If you give your notebook to someone else, it's very user friendly.

Comment: Szabolcs, you are right, I may be doing things in an unnatural way. I don't have a specific problem, it's more of a general problem. There will always be input parameter to a problem, there will always be output and then there is all the rest (function definitions, calculations etc). What I want to achieve is to only see the inputs and outputs and be able to change inputs and produce corresponding outputs without seeing the rest.

Comment: @FrankZander The right way to do that is to define a function that takes the input parameters, then all the code you need to see is `fun[parameters]`.

Comment: I know that would be possible but it doesn't really do the trick either. If there are several outputs I see all of these function calls. So, I guess it can't be done then.

Comment: @FrankZander I don't understand what you mean by "If there are several outputs I see all of these function calls."

Comment: To put it differently: so seem to be looking to develop an efficient workflow.  What you are asking is certainly possible.  People here could spend half an hour to create a ready made solution which lets you select two cells, press a button, and have them linked.  You will not be able to understand how this solution actually works without spending many hours to study notebook programming, so if something breaks, you won't be able to fix it easily.  Also, as a long time user of Mathematica, I don't believe that the workflow you describe is a good one; I think that once you get comfortable ...

Comment: ... with Mathematica, you'd stop using it anyway, and go for something better such as function definitions.  This sums up why people won't post a full answer: it's possible, but not worth the effort.  If you do decide to work on it anyway, one way is: you'd need to first add a unique identifier to the second cell (you can use `CellTags`), then you'd need to change the `CellEvaluationFunction` of the first cell to make it evaluate both.  The program that does this can conveniently be triggered using a palette `Button`.

Comment: Check here to get started with notebook programming: [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ManipulatingNotebooksFromTheKernel.html)

Answer (score 2):

To do this with two sequential input cells followed by an output cell is straight forward. If the cells do not follow one another then you'll need to use cell tags and the code below will not work.

**1.** First input cell type your code and the following two lines after it:

```
(* your code *)
x = 3;
y = 4;
(* add this after your code and at the end of the first input cell *)
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Cell];
FrontEndTokenExecute[EvaluationNotebook[], "Evaluate"]
```

**2.** In the next input cell that you want hidden do the same:

```
(* your code *)
x^2 + y
(* add this after your code and at the end of the second input cell *)
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, Cell];
FrontEndTokenExecute[EvaluationNotebook[], "OpenCloseGroup"];
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, Cell];
```

Now when you change parameters in input cell #1 and evaluate that cell, input cell #2 will evaluate, close and only the new output displayed. So here is the set up with all cells open:

[image]

now change the value of `y`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have one output then there is simple trick but it may not be the efficient one.

create a section for the cell that you want to hide and hide the section .

create a section after that.

Then use % to bring the last output which is what you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

1. Create the two input cells you describe (1. parameters and 2. code).
2. Group them together in a cell group (Menu: Cell > Grouping > Group Cells Together -or- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + `g`).
3. Select only the code cell, and set it to be closed (Cell > Cell Properties > (untick) Open). You see this cell below with the very small bracket under the parameters cell.
4. Now place the following code before your input cell group (and not in the same group)

   ```
   Button[
     "Evaluate",
     SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, CellGroup]
     SelectionEvaluateCreateCell[EvaluationNotebook[]]
   ]
   ```

   This will produce a button before your input cells which, when clicked, should evaluate the cell group containing your input (parameters and code) and produce an output cell. If you wanted to add `a` and `b`, it should look something like this, where the closed "code" cell contains `a + b`.

[image]

If you wish you can also close the cell that produced the button via step 3 above for visual elegance.